# Ajax issue with posting to a node/express endpoint

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax

It's been a bit since I used JQuery/Ajax instead of axios to connect to an endpoint, what am i doing wrong here?

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express()
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var path = require('path');

var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  

      res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  

      res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
  

      res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');
  

      res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  
      // Pass to next layer of middleware
      next();
  });

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../public/src', 'index.html'))

})

app.listen(port, function(error) {
  if(error){
    console.log(error);
  }
  console.log('Express is listening on port: ', port);
})
```

and my client side code is:

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
        function buttonClick() {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost:3000',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    'See me?': 'YEAH?'
                },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data) {
                    alert('This is the data: ', data)
                },
                error: function(error) {
                    alert('This is an error: ', error)
                }
            })
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <h3>Hello world</h3>


    <button onclick="buttonClick()"> Click Me! </button>


</body>

</html>
```

Whenever I hit the click me button, I get an error:

```js
POST http://localhost:3000/ 404 (Not Found)
(anonymous) @ VM174:1
send @ jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4
ajax @ jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4
buttonClick @ (index):11
onclick @ (index):33
VM174:1 XHR failed loading: POST "http://localhost:3000/".
```

Does anyone know why this is happening? By the way, I'm always getting a console log on the server when I refresh the page. The only time that console log should be happening is when the AJAX post gets called. It seems to be called on each refresh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have a post handler on server side, you only got a get handler.

change it to post or add a new post endpoint to your server.

```html
app.post('/', function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.body);
  ......
})
```

Comment: yeah it must be late, you're totally right. Answers both my questions at the same time.

Comment: to add onto my own question, now I get the post to work, but even though I see the console log on my server, the ajax call keeps showing me an error, even if i just send it a res.sendStatus(200).

Comment: just for the sake of testing, could you please try res.status(200).json({})
And what is the error you mentioned above?

Comment: it mentions that OK is not defined, which is odd. also on the server side it says that can't set headers after they are sent.

Comment: Is this a server error or a frontend error? Either one, it indicates that you are trying to use a variable called 'OK' without defining it.

Comment: if i delete the datatype parameter from the ajax call on the front end and do res.send('sdafdsf') on the backend, I get no error from the ajax call. But the sdafdsf text doesn't appear on the alert.

Comment: Ahh right, I see where you problem is. you set datatype to be 'JSON' which asks your server to send a JSON response but your server post endpoint is not sending a json payload back. That why you got that error. 
So first thing first, what type of data the frontend is expecting to get from server? that what 'datatype' is used for, meanwhile your server needs to send correct type of data.
so add dataType: 'json' back to your ajax call and change the server endpoint to return res.status(200).json({message: 'blabla'})